# Use pd.pivot_table, but no any result

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, pivot-table

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1=pd.read_csv('train.csv')
df1=df1.drop("Cabin",axis=1)
df1['Embarked'].fillna(method='ffill',inplace=True)
df1['Age'].fillna(value=df1['Age'].mean(),inplace=True)
pd.pivot_table(df1, index=['Survived'], values=['Age'], aggfunc='std', margins=True)
```

I was writing a ML code, Survived was int and Age was float, but there was no any respond after I ran the code.

In reference book, it will should show me an analysis form, but this code didn't.

Answer (score 2):

If you are working on IDE, not Jupyter Notebook, the code does not show any result.

You can create a new dataframe and see the pivoted result as follows:

```py
df2 = pd.pivot_table(df1, index=['Survived'], values=['Age'], aggfunc='std', margins=True)
print(df2)
```

If you just want to see the result without assigning the pivoted dataframe:

```py
print(pd.pivot_table(df1, index=['Survived'], values=['Age'], aggfunc='std', margins=True))
```

Many examples assume that you are working on Jupyter Notebook, which shows/prints variables without `print` function.

Comment: I saw the result! Thank you!

Comment: @E.HowardKe Happy to help you. It would appreciate if you accept my answer :)